# How to create a search box?

Tags: c#, .net, database, search, ms-access-2010

Now I have spent several hours trying to work something out and googling around and reading forums, but I have not found my answer!

I need to make some kind of "business application" as a project in my school, where I need to keep overview over a company's customers.
I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and Access 2010 and writing in C# using OleDb.

My question is:

How do I create a search box/form for an application to search for information in an access-database (.accdb).
I want to use a textbox where I write something from my database, for instance the company's name, and the push the search button. Now it should write all the information there is connected to the company's name, found in the database in a DataGrid.

Maybe it is too big a project, so if anyone got a less complicated search function doing something similar I would also appreciate that.

HERE IS THE CODE, GOT AN ERROR IN .Fill(dataset, "Food");.
InvalidOperationException was unhandled. Fill: SelectCommand.Connection has not been initialized.
Just testing a simple access database with one table named "Food" with FoodID, FoodName and Price inside.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetCustomers(textBox1.Text);
    }
        // Load Data from the DataSet into the DataGridView
        private void GetCustomers(string searchTerm)
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = 
            new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Niclas\Desktop\Skole\Programmering\Database\Food.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(
                "select * from Food where FoodID like ('" + searchTerm + "', connection");
                adapter.Fill(dataset, "Food");
            }

        // Get the table from the data set and bind the data to the grid
        this.dataGrid1 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();

        dataGrid1.DataContext = dataset.Tables[0];

        }
     }
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? How to create a searchbox? Put a textbox(es) on form. Then, under search button, use SQL queries via OleDB driver you're using to select data with WHERE clause as your  textbox(es) criteria.

Comment: Hello.. That is exactly my problem, but I am a newbie so I would appreciate some help with the coding :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code that you have that doesn't work?

Essentially on the Search Button's click event you would call a function to populate a DataGridView, eg:

```
GetCustomers(textBox1.Text);


// Load Data from the DataSet into the DataGridView
private void GetCustomers(string searchTerm)
{
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection connection = 
    new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
  {
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(
        "select * from customer where name like %" + searchTerm + "%", connection);
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "Customers");
  }

    // Get the table from the data set and bind the data to the grid
    DataGridView.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
}
```

I dont have Visual Studio on this PC so there might be syntax errors, but this should get you started.

Comment: I wouldn't do `"...%" + searchTerm + "%"` ... this is open to SQL injection in one form or another. If at all possible use parameteriesed queries. I realise this is a school project, but teaching good practice and avoiding this sort of issue is worth doing :-)

Comment: @ChrisJ - I agree and I should have given professional advise - to use SQL Server, MySQL,etc. But MS Access doesn't have stored proc's so how would you do parameterised queries? I'll leave SQL Injection hacks up to the OP to research...

Comment: Parameterised queries don't need to be sprocs. Dynamic queries can as well, by using placeholder parameters in the query. Microsoft have an article about it with Access and ADO -- I expect it'll be fairly similar for ADO.NET ... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190

Comment: Thanks a lot! Something like this I have been looking for. Will this work if I c/p and ofcourse edit the source and from/where?

Comment: Got the application up running with the following code. But when I type "1" in my textbox (to find nr 1 foodid in my access database) I get an error :( Something with a syntaxerror in "FoodID like %1%".

* Updated post with the code.

Comment: Not sure if I should highlight you, but I'll give it a try, cheers.
@JeremyThompson

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this when I was working as an intern. The way I got around this was to create a form for each type of data I was searching on and then ran a filter on the BindingSource attached to the data grid view. Another neat touch I added was that this filter ran on key stroke, so it automatically as you were typing.

I had a method that was something like this (this has been converted from VB):

```
private void Search()
{
    string[] strSplitString = null;
    string strSearchString = "";
    strSplitString = Strings.Split(txtSearch.Text.Trim);

    // Check to see if there are any strings
    if (strSplitString.Count == 1) {
        // Construct the search string
        strSearchString = "FirstName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%' Or MiddleName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%' Or LastName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%'";

    } else if (strSplitString.Count > 1) {
        // Construct the string
        strSearchString = "(FirstName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%' Or MiddleName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%' Or LastName Like '%" + strSplitString[0] + "%')";

        // For each word add it to the search string
        for (intWord = 1; intWord <= (strSplitString.Count - 1); intWord++) {
            strSearchString += " And (FirstName Like '%" + strSplitString[intWord] + "%' Or MiddleName Like '%" + strSplitString[intWord] + "%' Or LastName Like '%" + strSplitString[intWord] + "%')";
        }
    }

    // Filter the binding source
    BindingSource.Filter = strSearchString;
}
```

There may be better ways out there, but this project was also against a rather large access database and seemed to work quite well

Comment: I wouldn't do `"...%" + strSplitString[0] + "%"` ... this is open to SQL injection in one form or another. If at all possible use parameteriesed queries. I realise this is a school project, but teaching good practice and avoiding this sort of issue is worth doing :-) [I also think I'm suffering deja'vu]

Comment: @ChrisJ Very true. But if I recall from when I created this application it was rather a laborious task trying to mitigate SQL injections in Access. My personal preference would be to not use Access but something like SQL Server Compact Edition and use EF on top to prevent that kind of attack

Comment: You don't need EF ... see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190 for how to do queries with ADO; it shouldn't take too much to translate this into ADO.NET.

Comment: @ChrisJ I forgot all about that. It probably is an easier way of achieving the desired effect. EF can be quite clunky in places

Comment: Hi.. Does this work if I have a textbox and under click button I copy/paste this?